# Scrapy - Selecting and crawling a specific type of sitemap nodes

Tags: python, xml, scrapy, web-crawler, sitemap

[This](https://www.dfimoveis.com.br/sitemap_index.xml) is the sitemap of the website I'm crawling. The 3rd and 4th `<sitemap>` nodes have the urls which goes to the item details. Is there any way to apply crawling logic only to those
nodes? (like selecting them by their indices)

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    sitemap_urls = [
        'https://www.dfimoveis.com.br/sitemap_index.xml',
    ]

    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/somehow targeting the 3rd and 4th node', 'parse_item')
    ]


    def parse_item(self, response):
        # scraping the item
```

Comment: *nodes have the item details* - no such details - they contain **detalhes** in their `loc` item. Did you want to filter by that word?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I meant they have the url which goes to the item details. Sorry for not being clear, I'm editing my post. I'm trying to scrape item details from the urls inside those nodes.

Comment: clarify what is *item details* ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Each url inside the 3rd and 4th node is an item. If I can select only those nodes, I am going to send requests to the urls and scrape item details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use **SitemapSpider**, just use *regex* and standard spider.

```py
def start_requests(self):
    sitemap = 'https://www.dfimoveis.com.br/sitemap_index.xml'
    yield scrapy.Request(url=sitemap, callback=self.parse_sitemap)

def parse_sitemap(self, response):
    sitemap_links = re.findall(r"<loc>(.*?)</loc>", response.text, re.DOTALL)
    sitemap_links = sitemap_links[2:4]  # Only 3rd and 4th nodes.
        for sitemap_link in sitemap_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=sitemap_link, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be “sitemap_links[2:4]” for the 3rd and 4th nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy’s `Spider` subclasses, including `SitemapSpider` are meant to make very common scenarios very easy.

You want to do something that is rather uncommon, so you should read the source code of `SitemapSpider`, try to understand what it does, and either subclass `SitemapSpider` overriding the behavior you want to change or directly write your own spider from scratch based on the code of `SitemapSpider`.